# How can I ensure that two sequelize queries will be ran on the same connection?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to utilize the `GET_LOCK` function family from MariaDB, on an app, that uses **Sequelize** to manage connections to the database. The `GET_LOCK` statement, according to the documentation, tries to acquire a lock for a given connection, which then can be released either explicitly by the connection which acquired it, or it will be automatically released when the connection exits. A function example on what I am trying to do is as follows:

```
function async createIfNotExists(sequelize) {
     const lockGet = await sequelize.query("SELECT GET_LOCK('my_lock', 2) as lockResult;");
     if (lockGet[0].lockResult == 0) throw 'lock-was-blocked';
     .... perform bunch of additional queries here while holding the lock ...
     const lockRelease = await sequelize.query("RELEASE_LOCK('my_lock');");
}
```

The problem is, that how will I know, that the first query, which acquires the lock, and the last query, which releases the same lock will be ran on the same `MariaDB` connection through sequelize?

Comment: Have you consider transaction with lock?  https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/ & https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/#locks

Comment: I know that basically, if I put everything under a transaction, I will ensure the same connection, but what I am interested in, is if there any way, to perform queries on a specific connection with sequelize, or not.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what do you mean by "a specific connection"?  use-case could be helpful?

Comment: Basically, what I mean is that instead of using an arbitrary available connection from the connection pool, when trying to perform a query, use, a specific connection from the same pool. Given the above example, ensure that the first query executed on sequelize, will be run from the same connection, then the last query (get and release lock)

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, locks are automatically released when the connection exits. So it doesn't play well with pooling.

You can create a separate instance of Sequelize that doesn't use pooling. In the [documentation](https://Closing%20the%20connection%20Sequelize%20will%20keep%20the%20connection%20open%20by%20default,%20and%20use%20the%20same%20connection%20for%20all%20queries.%20If%20you%20need%20to%20close%20the%20connection,%20call%20sequelize.close()%20(which%20is%20asynchronous%20and%20returns%20a%20Promise).) they mention

> #### Closing the connection
>
> Sequelize will keep the connection open by default, and use the same
> connection for all queries. If you need to close the connection, call
> sequelize.close() (which is asynchronous and returns a Promise).

So unless a timeout is otherwise configured, you should be able to use `GET_LOCK` and release it in code that runs later.

You also don't necessarily need to do this with MariaDB. The locking doesn't lock anything in the DB itself. It just means that other processes requesting a lock will see they can't do so, and it's up to the process itself to stop proceeding. You could just as well do this with Redis and it wouldn't have the connection lifetime limitation or issues with pooling.